# How can I extract artist name and song name from filename?

Tags: python

I have a list of mp3 files name like "Artist Name - Song Name.mp3". I wanna extract artist name and song name in their own individual variables. How can I do that? Note that they don't have tags on them.

Answer (score 1):

I made a Python library just for this. Here is the Pypi link for details: https://pypi.org/project/SongNameSplit/

Install:

```
pip install SongNameSplit
```

Sample Code:

```
import SongNameSplit

result = SongNameSplit.namesplit("Coldplay - Hymn For The Weekend (Official Video)")

print("The name of the song is: ", result['songname'])
print("The name of the artist is: ", result['artist'])
```

It is very simple to use and gives fairly accurate results. Please note that it may be a little slow (takes about 10 seconds).

Comment: This sounds exactly like the solution I'm looking for, but it doesn't work for a lot of strings, giving the error `SongNameSplit.NonStandardSongTitle: This title does not look like a standard title`.  Perhaps I should do some preprocessing to the string, or need another way to check for more nonstandard formats?

Comment: @Nuclear_Man_D Yes, it does require a fairly standard song title, something like the one you would find on a YouTube video. It is not really designed to handle general strings without a structure. I would recommend using a different method if your strings are more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```py
import os

fname = "Artist Name - Song Name.mp3"
artistname = fname.split(" - ")[0]
songname = os.path.splitext("".join(fname.split(" - ")[1:]))[0]
```

Edit: @ThiefMaster suggested to use `os.path.splitext`, this edited solution makes dashes in the filename possible.

Comment: You want `.split(' - ', 1)` in case the song title also contains `' - '`. Also, better use [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to split filename and extension